# Format RichText in BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#

I am working on a file listener (for txt files) using `FileSystemWatcher` and want to append all new lines to a `RichTextBox`. Format new text to rich text needs alot of cpu power, so I decided to use a BackgroundWorker for this.

The program is still working, but form hangs when I lock MS Windows and relogin. Seems as BackgroundWorker thread is blocking the UI thread. There is no other effect of using `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke` for AppendText to RichTextBox.

When I pass the unformatted text to `e.Result` of `bw_DoWork` everything is working fine (no blocking threads). The temporary RichTextBox is not attached to the main form. How can I solve the "hang" problem?

Logic before code sample: `FileSystemWatcher` event `Changed` starts `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync`.

```
StringBuilder unformattedText;

private void bw_DoWork( object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e )
{
    // Write all new lines for this file to 
    // StringBuilder variable unformattedText
    ReadFromFile (...)

    // Need a temporary RichTextBox to create new formatted text
    RichTextBox tempRtb = new RichTextBox();

    // Split new unformatted text with regex, format some tokens 
    // and append each to temporary RichTextBox tempRtb
    HighlightWords( tempRtb, unformattedText );

    e.Result = tempRtb.Rtf;
}

private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted( object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e )
{
    string rtfText = e.Result as string;

    // Append text to main RichTextBox 
    if (rtb.InvokeRequired)
    {
            rtb.BeginInvoke(
                new MethodInvoker( delegate
                {
                    AppendRichText( rtb, rtfText );
                } ) );
    }
    else
    { 
        AppendRichText( rtb, rtfText );
    }
}

private void AppendRichText(RichTextBox rtb, string text)
{
    // Append formatted text at the end of the RichTextBox
    rtb.Select( rtb.TextLength, 0 );
    rtb.SelectedRtf = text;

    rtb.ScrollToCaret();
}
```

Note: These are only the code parts to understand the problem. It's not complete.

Comment: `RunWorkerCompleted` should already be in the UI thread, so you shouldn't need the `InvokeRequired` branch, just call `AppendRichText`.  Seems odd to have the rtb parameter since obviously rtb is the local RichTextBox control already accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RichTextBox` cannot be created or manipulated on the worker thread.  You *MUST* do it on the UI thread.

The `bw_RunWorkerCompleted` is run on the UI thread, so `BeginInvoke` is not required.

You need to move all the code after `ReadFromFile` into `bw_RunWorkerCompleted` and you will not need a temp `RichTextBox` anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I changed my code, so `HighlightWords` is called in `bw_RunWorkerCompleted` now and appends each token directly to main `RichTextBox` without the use of a temporary one. But this is much slower for small text files already. I appended `Application.DoEvents();` after `rtb.ScrollToCaret();`, so UI thread is not blocked and gets repaint. This looks smooth as each line is written to UI. In a second try I used the temporary `RichTextBox` in `HighlightWords` to send the whole formatted textblock to UI. This is much faster, but user must wait. I will try something between both.